# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.tours index: rating_1 dup key: { rating: null }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.tours index: rating_1 dup key: { rating: null }

i dont understand this error when i create data using postman, saying dup key: {rating:null}, there is no any rating key in the shcema where this come from ? why im able to create one time only.

here's my code(tourSchema)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name:{
    type:String, 
    required:[true, 'tour must have name'], 
    unique:true,
    trim: true
},
ratingAverage: Number,
ratingQty:Number,
discount:Number,
price:{
    type:String, 
    required:[true, 'tour must have price']
},
summary:{
    type:String, 
    required:[true, 'tour must have summary'],
    trim:true
},
description:{
    type:String, 
    trim:true
},
imageCover:{
    type:String, 
    required:[true, 'tour must have imageCover'],
    trim:true
},
images: [String],
createdAt:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now()
},
startDate:[Date]
})
const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);

 module.exports = Tour;
```

here's data im trying to add

```
{
"name":"the mountain explorer",
"ratingAverage":4,
"ratingQty":1,
"price":400,
"summary":"this is mountain explorer near to solua, best known for the river around it",
"description":"this mountain is located at the top of siraha mountain, has so many rivers around it",
"imageCover":"nepal_tour_cover-1.jpg",
"images":["nepal_tour-1.jpg", "nepal_tour-2.jpg", "nepal_tour-3.jpg"],
"startDate":["2020-03-12,12:44", "2020-04-12,12:54"]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have a unique index for rating inside that collection. As you didn't specify a rating while adding, the rating is null, therefore you have this error after the first.
As the subsequent data you trying to add does not have a rating as well, their rating is null which conflict with the index.

Firstly, head over to your mongo console.

Run this command

```
db.<collection>.getIndexes()
```

You should have a record of something like this

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "rating" : 1
    },
    "name" : "rating"
}
```

Next, run this command to drop the index

```
db.<collection>.dropIndex("<index name>")
```